# CGI.escape and URLEncoder.encode result are not matching

Tags: java, ruby, cgi

I have to write ruby code in to java. During this we are encoding one hash value. To do that in Ruby client has used CGI.escape() method, similarly I have used URLEncoder.encode() in java. but the end result is not matching.

**Ruby script part:**

```
    hash = "gFH6B8aN+yReGkBL2QS7X4O7d98="
    puts "hash: " + hash
    puts "escaped hash: " + CGI.escape(hash)
```

Ruby Output:

```
   hash: gFH6B8aN+yReGkBL2QS7X4O7d98=
   escaped hash: gFH6B8aN%2ByReGkBL2QS7X4O7d98%3D%0A
```

Java Code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)

{
    String hash = "gFH6B8aN+yReGkBL2QS7X4O7d98=";
    String encodedString = URLEncoder.encode(hash, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println("hash :" + hash);
    System.out.println("encodedString::" + encodedString);
}
```

Java Output:

```
 hash :gFH6B8aN+yReGkBL2QS7X4O7d98=
 encodedString::gFH6B8aN%2ByReGkBL2QS7X4O7d98%3D
```

As you can see there is extra %0A appended to the Ruby result. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%0A` denotes a line break (`"\n"`).

Perhaps you got the text from some input source (like user input, or a file), and you need to [`chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) the line break?

```
hash = "gFH6B8aN+yReGkBL2QS7X4O7d98=\n"
puts "hash: " + hash
# => hash: gFH6B8aN+yReGkBL2QS7X4O7d98=
puts "escaped hash: " + CGI.escape(hash.chomp) 
# => escaped hash: gFH6B8aN%2ByReGkBL2QS7X4O7d98%3D
```